# CakePHP/Croogo: Searching for strings with some special chars returns no results

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I noticed there is a bug in Croogo's NodesController::search() when searching for words with some non-ascii chars on them e.g. 'üäö'. If I search for example for 'Steuergeräte' (german) I get no results, even though I should. If I search for 'Steuergerate' (which would be misspelled in german) I get the desired results. Which is totally weird.

A direct query on the db I works fine:

"SELECT * FROM i18n WHERE content LIKE '%Steuergeräte%';"

Which returns the expected records.

But it's not a general problem with unicode-chars, as for example, searching for a japanese word worked as expected. So this only affect some chars.

Cakephp: 2.4.0, Croogo: 1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause of the problem.

On the search-view, the string to be searched for is cleaned with:

```
     $q = Sanitize::clean($this->request->params['named']['q']);
```

Which among other things runs html_entities on the string as default, when `'encode' => true` is set (default). This would turn e.g. `ö` into `&ouml;` and then search for words with html-entities on them.

I got a workaround by doing:

```
     $q = $this->request->params['named']['q'];
     // Use encode=false on Sanitize::clean to prevent äüöß etc. getting
     // replaced by html entities. And strip tags manually first to prevent
     // html injected strings.
     $q = strip_tags($q);
     $q = Sanitize::clean($q, array('encode' => false));
```

**Note**: If like in my case, TinyMCE is set with `'entity_encoding' => 'raw'` then the body field in the nodes table would contain äöü instead of htmlentities as well, which IMO is a far better practice as replacing them with htmlentities. Per default though, tinymce replaces chars with htmlentities, so the body field would work with the default search behaviour of Croogo/Cakephp. But searching, for example, in the title-field wouldn't.

**Update**

Ok, as mark comments suggested, sanitizing and using cake's paginate method, is not necessary, so the Sanitize part can be skipped. I also found using htmlspecialchars even better as strip_tags, as strip_tags wouldn't take care of e.g. '&', and on the body, tinyMCE saves those as html_entities. So the updated code would look like this:

```
     $q = htmlspecialchars($this->request->params['named']['q']);
     // go on with searching for nodes on paginate-method
```

Comment: I would not strip_tags/sanitize in the first place.

Comment: Could you explain why and what would you do instead?

Comment: The first sentence at http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/ - let Cake take care of escaping when using find() etc to retrieve results. Nothing else is either necessary nor useful in this case.

Comment: Sorry, but you totally missunderstood the problem here. It's about a search field, which anyway should contain no tags at all. That string is displayed again in a "Your Results for: <here-the-search-phrase>" ... and I definetely don't want any html tags in there. So why wouldn't I strip_tags? And about your article: I'm obviously not using a model for the search field, so the input isn't validated in any way, so that sentence "ONLY validate, do not sanitize or strip things off the input." doesn't even apply here. Please don't comment like that without fully understanding the situation first.

Comment: why? if someone looks for "<hello>" or "some&other" or "he/she/it" he has the right to search for exactly this term.. no need to modify the input... same goes for ANY special char that is a valid db character

Comment: "some&other" would work. Only xml-tags would be stripped off, and it would be very unlikely if someone would be looking for <hello> on our site. If that wouldn't be the case, then we would be using html_entities anyway. But this is about _not_ using html-entities and just saving utf8 on the db. As I said, if someone would try to look for "Something</div>" it would break the layout, so why allow that? I think everything (constructive) has been said and further discussing this will end up in a pointless discussion about 2 different situtations which won't help anyone.

Comment: Just, to leave things clear, I agree with you about letting most content unescaped on the db (that's my whole point) but I disagree not removing html-tags from a search term, at least not on our case, where the users are looking for content and shouldn't be looking for html-tags. Any other tag-like-string in the content would be html_entities anyway. About the pointless use of sanitizing input before using it on paginate... I don't know. That's the way it was programmed on croogo and I don't know the paginate method enough to comment on that, so I would have to take a closer look to it first.

Comment: **Update**: I reviewed the code block and about the sanitize part, I checked it and you're right, it's not needed, as the cake paginate methods already take care of it. I will suggest to the croogo team, to just remove the line. About stripping the tags, it turned out to be even better to use htmlspecialchars instead of strip_tags, as some chars like & are saved as html_entities even with entity_encoding => raw on tinyMCE. So I would just exchange strip_tags through htmlspecialchars there. On a title or excerpt the '&' still wouldn't be found. So it's still not perfect, but almost.